# Не запускается дочерний поток в android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

При запуске потока он не работает.
Просто не выводит залодженные строки
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что может быть, ошибок не выводит

```
public void RegAuth(View view){

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        EditText phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPhone);

        if(button.getText().toString().equals(this.reg)){
            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.taxi_full.Registration"));
        } if(button.getText().toString().equals(this.auth)) {
            String url = URL_API+phone.getText().toString();
            new Thread(() -> {
               try {
                   GsonParser parser = new GsonParser();
                   JsonWriter.jsonFileWriter(HttpApi.getId(url));
                   Root_user_one root = parser.parse();
                   Log.d("---ParseLogin---", root.getPhone());
                   Log.d("---Http---", HttpApi.getId(url));
                   JsonWriter.jsonClear();
                   Log.d("---Http---",HttpApi.getId(url));
                   //startActivity(new Intent("com.example.taxi_full.SMS_Code"));

               } catch (IOException e) {
                   Log.d("---ThreadEx--", e.getMessage());
               }
            });

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При вызове конструктора поток только лишь создаётся, но не начинает своё выполнение. Для того, чтобы созданный при помощи `new` поток был запущен, необходим вызвать для него метод `start()`.

То есть, например, в такой записи на экран ничего не будет выведено, так как поток не запускается, а только создаётся:

```
new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Hello, word"));
```

А при такой записи он уже выполнится, так как не только создаётся, но и сразу же запускается:

```
new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Hello, word")).start();
```

Для наглядности это можно даже записать вот так:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Hello, word"));
thread.start();
```

Так что если переписать код в вашей программе следующим образом, то поток должен будет отработать:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        GsonParser parser = new GsonParser();
        JsonWriter.jsonFileWriter(HttpApi.getId(url));
        Root_user_one root = parser.parse();
        Log.d("---ParseLogin---", root.getPhone());
        Log.d("---Http---", HttpApi.getId(url));
        JsonWriter.jsonClear();
        Log.d("---Http---",HttpApi.getId(url));
        //startActivity(new Intent("com.example.taxi_full.SMS_Code"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.d("---ThreadEx--", e.getMessage());
      }
}).start();
```